# Continuity of the embeddings $j_i:M_i \to \bigoplus_k M_k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, vector-spaces, category-theory

I have two questions on the direct sum of two Banach spaces. Before the questions, I would like to point out the below universal property of the direct sum I noticed from Wikipedia. My first question is, how do we prove the embeddings $j_i$ must be continuous? My second question is, how do we prove the universal property from the constructive definition (on Wikipedia too)?

Remark: the universal property below is expressed in the general language of modules, but it translates directly to Banach spaces.

***Universal property**:*

*In the language of category theory, the direct sum is a coproduct and hence a colimit in the category of left $R$-modules, which means that it is characterized by the following universal property. For every $i$ in $I$, consider the natural embedding
$$
j_i: M_i \rightarrow \bigoplus_{i \in I} M_i
$$
which sends the elements of $M_i$ to those functions which are zero for all arguments but $i$. Now let $M$ be an arbitrary $R$-module and $f_i: M_i \rightarrow M$ be arbitrary $R$-linear maps for every $i$, then there exists precisely one $R$ linear map
$$
f: \bigoplus_{i \in I} M_i \rightarrow M
$$
such that $f \circ j_i=f_i$ for all $i$.*

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your questions are the following:

1. If $ {\bigl(\bigoplus_{i\in\mathsf I} E_i\xrightarrow{\iota^k} E_k\bigr)}_{k\in \mathsf I} $ is a coproduct in the category $ \mathsf{Ban} $ of Banach spaces and bounded linear maps, how do we prove that all the injections $ \iota^k\colon E_i\to \bigoplus_{i\in I}E_i $ are continuous?
2. If $ E_1,\dots, E_n $ are Banach spaces, how do we prove that $ \bigoplus_{j = 1}^n E_j = \bigl(\prod_{j = 1}^n E_j,\lVert{-}\lVert\bigl) $, where
   $$
   \lVert{(x_1,\dots,x_n)}\rVert = \max_{j = 1}^n {\lVert x_j\rVert}_{E_j}$$
   is a coproduct in $ \mathsf{Ban} $?

The answer to 1. is that the $ \iota^k $ are continuous by definition, since you are taking the coproduct in $ \mathsf{Ban} $, and a bounded linear map is always continuous.

To answer 2., let $ E $ be a Banach space and let $ f_j\colon E_j\to E $ be bounded linear maps. Now let $ f\colon \bigoplus_{j = 1}^n E_j\to E $ be the map that results from the universal property of $ \bigoplus_{j = 1}^n E_j $ as a coproduct of vector spaces. Can you show that $ f $ is bounded?

Comment: Thank you, @giovanniadeodato. 

In terms of 1, I have read the definition of the co-product on Wikipedia and there is no reason for the so-called canonical injections, which are you say are bounded and linear, to actually be injections. So there is no need for these embeddings to be the canonical injections referred to in the definition of the coproduct

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coproduct.   In terms of two, I am not too sure if you understood my question. My question is, how do you prove the universal property is satisfied for the direct sum as constructed in Wikipedia?

Comment: Indeed, my question is answered by answering whether the direct sum as constructed on Wikipedia is a coproduct in $\mathsf{Ban}$. What makes me suspect that you might have misunderstood my question is, how do you know that $f $ as resulting from the universal property of the direct sum exists, if we don’t even know the universal property of the direct sum actually holds?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum_of_modules#Construction_for_two_vector_spaces

Comment: A coproduct in $ \mathsf{Ban} $ of $ E_1,\dots, E_n $ is the datum of an object $ C\in \mathsf{Ban} $ and morphisms (i.e., bounded linear mappings) $ i^k\colon E_k\to C $ for $ k = 1,\dots,n $ such that some universal property holds. The maps $ i^k $ are part of the definition of a coproduct. In an arbitrary category the "injection" mappings $ i^k $ need not to be injective (maybe the $ i^k $ are not functions at all!).

Comment: As for you second comment. You know that the pair of $ \prod_{j = 1}^n E_n $ (the set-theoretic product of the underlying sets of the $ E_j $) and of $ \iota^k\colon E_k\to \prod_{j = 1}^n E_j $ for $ k = 1,\dots,n $ where $ \iota^k(x) = (0,\dots,x,\dots,0) $ ($ x $ is in the $ k $-th position) is a coproduct in the category $ \mathsf{Vect}_{\mathbb C} $ of (say) complex vector spaces. (Continues)

Comment: (Continued from above) To show that the same pair is a coproduct in $ \mathsf{Ban} $ then you only need to show that the map $ f\colon E\to \prod_{j = 1}^nE_j $ that comes from the universal property of the pair $ (\prod_{j = 1}^nE_j,(\iota^j)_{j = 1}^n) $ in $ \mathsf{Vect}_{\mathbb C} $ is bounded. (You need also to show the uniqueness of such $ f $, but this is trivial).

Comment: The boundedness will follow from the fact that the max of bounded functions is bounded itself.

My problem is still with the canonical injections. We need to choose these so that they are morphisms and will allow for the universal property to hold. Pick the canonical injections to be the canonical injections arising from $   \bigoplus_{j = 1}^n E_j$ as a coproduct of vector spaces, they will be linear and in particular they will be the natural embeddings. How to show these embeddings are bounded? Easily, from the definition of the norm on your $\textsf{Ban}$ coproduct as the max.

Comment: So my question: it is crucial to define some norm on the $\textsf{Ban}$ coproduct in order to show it is a coproduct?

Comment: Objects of $ \mathsf{Ban} $ are pairs $ (E,\lVert{-}\rVert) $ where $ E $ is a vector space and $ \lVert{-}\rVert $ is a norm. Given pairs $ ((E{,\lVert{-}\rVert}_j) : j = 1,\dots,n) $, you need to find a new pair $ (C,\lVert{-}\rVert) $ and mappings $ i^j\colon (E_j,{\lVert{-}\rVert}_j)\to (C,\lVert{-}\rVert) $ of $ \mathsf{Ban} $ such that so and so. How do you do that? Let $ E := \bigoplus_{j = 1}^nE_n $ (the coproduct in $ \mathsf{Vect} $) of the $ E_j $s, and let $ i^k := \iota^k\colon E_k\to \bigoplus_{j = 1}^nE_j $. (Continues)

Comment: (Continued) Now, endow $C$ with the usual product norm. At this point you can check that the pair $ (C,{\lVert{-}\rVert}_\infty) $ (where ${\lVert{-}\rVert}_\infty$ is the product norm) has the universal property of a coproduct. How? Pick a space $ (E,\lVert{-}\rVert) $ and $ Ban $-maps $ f_k\colon E\to C $. Now use the fact that $ C $ (together with the $ i_j $s) is a coproduct in $ \mathsf{Vect} $. After you have obtained a *linear* map $ f\colon C\to E $, all you need to check is that $ f $ is bounded. But this is easy. (Maybe you need also to check the uniqueness condition at some point!)

Comment: There is a typo in my previous comment. Let $ C $ be $ \bigoplus_{j = 1}^nE_j $. We will need the letter $ E $ later...

Comment: I think you meant “$\mathsf{Ban}$ maps $f_k:E_k\to E$“?

Comment: The map $f$ must be unique since it is the unique $f$ map arising from $C$ being a coproduct in $\mathsf{Vect}$. In order for $f$ to be the unique map giving that $C$ is a coproduct in $\mathsf{Ban}$, we need even more restrictions (not just linear, but linear and bounded)