# Why is the direct sum of two vector spaces a categorical coproduct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, category-theory, direct-sum

Define the direct sum of two vector spaces as per Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum_of_modules#Construction_for_two_vector_spaces

Why does this satisfy the definition of the categorical coproduct?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coproduct

My best guess is that the “canonical injections” can be taken to be the the embeddings $j_i:V_i\to \bigoplus_k V_k$ since they are morphisms (because they are linear maps) and they yield that whenever $h_i:V_i \to Z$ are linear maps into a vector space $Z$, there exists a unique linear map $H: \bigoplus_k V_k\to Z$ such that $$H\circ j_i = h_i, \forall i.\quad (1)$$ Indeed, defining $H(v_1\oplus v_2 \oplus …):= h_1(v_1)+h_2(v_2)+…$ we get existence of $H$ and for uniqueness we realise that, supposing $\tilde{H}$ another linear map such that (1) holds:
$\tilde{H}(v_1\oplus v_2 \oplus …)=\tilde{H}(v_1\oplus 0 \oplus …) + \tilde{H}(0\oplus  v_2 \oplus0 \oplus …)$$= \sum_k \tilde{H}(…\oplus 0 \oplus v_k\oplus 0 \oplus …)= \sum_k \tilde{H}\circ j_k(v_k)=  \sum_k  h_k (v_k)=H(v_1\oplus v_2 \oplus …)$.

Is my proof accurate?

Comment: In the category of vector spaces, the coproduct is the product, namely the direct sum. So it is enough to note that the direct sum satisfies the axioms of a categorial product.

Comment: That’s what I’m trying to “note” (or “prove”). Have I succeeded in “noting it” in the right way?

Comment: You have linked only the coproduct. Here is the categorial [product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)), if you want to verify this.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4528016/continuity-of-the-embeddings-j-im-i-to-bigoplus-k-m-k). If you know it already for $R$-modules, then you have it for vector spaces, of course.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, now I understand what you meant. It is a millimetre simpler indeed to prove it satisfies the axioms of a product: let the $f:Y\to V_1\times V_2$ in Wikipedia's notation be defined through $f(y):= (f_1(y_1),f(y_2))$, since it is easy to see that this $f$ makes the diagram commute this proves existence. To prove it is unique, assuming another $\tilde{f}$   (and putting $\tilde{f}(y)=(\tilde{f}^1(y),\tilde{f}^2(y))$)  making the diagram commute we get $\pi_1\circ \tilde{f}(y)= \pi_1 [ (\tilde{f}^1(y), \tilde{f}^2(y))] = \tilde{f}^1(y) =   f_1(y)$ so indeed $\tilde{f} = f$